# How to set a date pickers date from a date string in swift

Tags: swift, datepicker

What is the correct way to set a date pickers date from a date string

```
let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/YY"
let convertedStartDate = dateFormatter.dateFromString("1/3/15")
startDatePicker.date = convertedStartDate!
```

This does not work, convertedStartDate = nil

Comment: I believe if you change your date format string to "d/M/YY" your formatter will work. By supplying two `d`'s and `M`'s you tell it there will be leading `0`'s for single digit days and months.

Comment: I tried that. No luck. And wouldn't work for most dates surely

Comment: Okay. Easier option. Use `dateFormatter.dateStyle = .ShortStyle`. That works for me in a playground.

Answer (score 8):

**You have to use "yy" instead of "YY"

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "d/M/yy"
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
if let startDate = formatter.date(from: "1/3/15") {
    print(startDate)  // 2015-03-01 03:00:00 +0000
}
```

**You can also create an extension to handle that for you as follow:**

```
extension String {
    func toDateFormatted(with string: String)-> Date? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "d/M/yy"
        formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = string
        return formatter.date(from: self)
    }
}
let string = "1/3/15"
if let date = string.toDateFormatted(with: "d/M/yy") {
     print(date)  // 2015-03-01 03:00:00 +0000
}
```

If you need a reference to help you format your date, you can use this one below:
[image]

Comment: nice catch on the lowercase `y`! I completely missed that in my original reading.

Comment: I didn't see it at first either. I only realized that when I've put it side by side with my extension.

Answer (score 1):

## Swift 3.0 version

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d/M/yy"
if let convertedStartDate = dateFormatter.date(from: "1/3/15") {
    ...
}
```